# Does bucketing two *large* tables in Hive *in the same way* help perform much more efficient joins?

Tags: join, hive, bigdata

Imagine the following situation I am planning:

1. Have two rather large tables stored in Hive, both containing different types of customer related information (say, although this is not exactly the case, a record of customer transactions in one and customer owned data in the other). **Let's call the tables A and B**.
2. Tables are large in the sense that **none of the tables fits completely in memory**. (There are 10 million customers and theres is a few kilobytes of info associated to each of them in each of the two tables)
3. Be careful enough to bucket both tables in exactly the same way, by a field present in both tables (customer_id, which is a bigint), and using the same number of buckets 100.

*I wonder whether this setup will, in any way, guarantee that a join (by customer_id) between both tables will be efficient*, in the sense that **very little shuffling of information between nodes** will be required. *I imagine this could the case, if for instance, there were a guarantee that the physical files corresponding to the same bucket in both tables are physically stored in the same (sets of nodes), i.e. if for every bucket i (in [0,99]) the file  A/part_0_000i  and the file  B/part_0_000i were physically stored in the same nodes and the same held for their replicas.*

Notes:

- I am aware that partitioning and bucketing are different and that the first essentially determines the structure of subdirectories, whereas the second on determines which file each record goes too. **This question is about bucketing only**
- Also, by number 2, **map-side joins are not an option here**, since,  as far as my understading goes, they require loading one of the tables completely within each mapper and doing the join completely there.

Answer (score 2):

Bucketing is used when there are too many levels in your data in which you want to partition by, or there are no good candidate partitions.

A concrete example would be partitioning on customerID in sales data.  You may have 20 thousand customers. Partitions would contain small amounts of data which is inefficient and have too many partitions also inefficient.  However you can hash the customerID and partition into 50 buckets for example.  Then when you are merging on customerID the job will only have to scan against what is in a bucket rather than the entire sum of all your data.

With ideal bucketing your buckets should contain some multiple of the file system block size.  Remember also that too many buckets or buckets that are built over varialbes not used as keys can be detrimental for other queries.

I have used them when I need to execute large jobs repeatedly. My queries time has been reduced significantly.  I tend to only use when my data is very big.  And big is relative to cluster size and capacity.

One great thing about bucketing is that they help ensure the bucketed partitions are of similar size.  If you partition over State for example, California will have huge partitions while other states are very small.

Bucketing is tactical and not an appropriate for all use cases.  Happy bucketing!

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications, but your answer does not address the question of whether bucketing two separate tables large tables will have a performance impact on joining them.  As mentioned in the question, my use case involves 10 million customers and I am planning to bucket in 100 buckets. That is 100.000 customers per bucket and with several kilobytes of data in each of the tables per customer, I have plenty of info to fill an hdfs block with a single bucket.

Comment: The ids are analogous to social security numbers and the last two digits are pretty evenly distributed, so this is a good field to bucket with. So the observation about using State for partitioning and skewing the resulting layout is not relevant here either.

Comment: I have listed the things to consider.  It does appear that certain queries you are performing would benefit from this scheme.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will definitely help. 
Bucketed tables are partitioned and sorted the same way, so they will be mergesorted, which works in linear time (n), otherwise the tables have to be sorted the same way first, which is usually nlog(n)

Comment: Could you comment on whether the bucketing specification will have any effect on the physical nodes the each bucket is stored?  I am a bit worried about too much network traffic when performng the join...

Comment: Well, that depends on the number of nodes in your cluster, and on the number of buckets. Buckets should be around the size of a block - or a small integer size. 
I wouldn't worry about the network transfer - remember that hadoop usually keeps 3 replicas and will try to schedule work where the data is.
When using bucketing, the main thing you should worry about is data skew, that is, that buckets are roughly the same size, that is, you bucket on a key that's evenly distributed. If you have one bucket much larger than the others, one reducer will take much longer than the others

Comment: But in general, there's not much difference in network traffic between bucketed and not bucketed when doing a join.